# saving running instance in netbeans

Tags: java, desktop-application, save, netbeans-6.9

I've created a application in Netbeans IDE 6.9. I want to save my running application. I actually select various things in my applications. I want that if I run my application again then those things should be selected. I want to save the running instance of my application. Can anyone help me with this?
-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java language and runtime system do not directly support this kind of thing.

If you want your application to save its state so that you can resume what you were doing later, you will have to code the state-saving mechanism yourself; e.g. by writing key data structures to a file or by keeping the persistent state in a database of some kind.

Incidentally, few programming languages directly support application checkpointing and resumption.  Some dialects of LISP do, as did "persistent programming languages" like PS-Algol and Napier-88.  But they are the exception rather than the rule.